# Refreshing component using Laravel Livewire emit doesn't work as expected

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I'm trying to toggle between a play and a pause button using laravel livewire. On click the component should refresh and the task should start. The task is getting started but the component doesn't refresh. Using the same functionality on pause works as expected.

My Component:

```
class RunTaskComponent extends Component
{

public $taskId;
public $status;
public $taskTime;
public $current_employee_id;
protected $listeners = ['refreshComponent' => '$refresh'];


public function mount($taskId, $current_employee_id){
    $this->taskId = $taskId;
    $this->current_employee_id = $current_employee_id;

    $this->taskTime = TaskTime::where('task_id',$taskId)->latest()->first();
    
}
 
public function runTask(){
    $task = Task::findOrFail($this->taskId);
    
    //Check if a user is already running a task
    $employeeTask = Task::where('employee_id',$this->current_employee_id)->pluck('task_id');
    $employeeRunningTask = TaskTime::whereIn('task_id',$employeeTask)->where('status',1)->get();

    if(count($employeeRunningTask) < 1){
        $tasktime = TaskTime::create([
            'task_id'=>$task->task_id,
            'play_time'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            'status'=>1,
        ]);
        $task->status_id = 10;
        $task->save();        
        $this->emit('refreshComponent');
    }
    else{
        session()->flash('message','Already running a task');
    }        
}
public function pauseTask(){
    $task=Task::findOrFail($this->taskId);
  

$tasktime=TaskTime::where('task_id',$task->task_id)->
where('pause_time',null)->latest()->first();
    $playtime=\Carbon\Carbon::parse($tasktime->play_time);
    $now=\Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $tasktime->pause_time=\Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $tasktime->duration = $playtime->diffInSeconds($now);
    $tasktime->status=0;
    $tasktime->save();
    $this->emit('refreshComponent');
}
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.run-task-component');
}
```

My Blade File

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @if (session()->has('message'))
                <span class="badge badge-primary running">{{ session('message') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @if($taskTime == null)
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" type="button" wire:click="runTask">
                    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-play-circle float-right"></i>
                    
                </button> 
            @elseif($taskTime->status == 1)
        
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button" wire:click="pauseTask">
                    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-pause-circle float-right"></i>            
                </button> <br/>
                <span class="badge badge-primary running">Running</span>
            
            @else
                
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" type="button" wire:click="runTask">
                    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-play-circle float-right"></i>
                    
                </button> 
            
            @endif
        </div>
       </div>    
    </div>
```

To summarize the emit in runTask() doesn't work as expected while pauseTask() works as expected. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJF52.jpg) is a small demo of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never updating the `public $taskTime`, which is the value that is linked to which button is meant to show. If the task is paused on load, when you run `pauseTask`, the change of `status` is processed and renders your change due to your third `if` statement.

In the case that your `$taskTime` is `null`, the play button will never disappear. If the `$taskTime` is set on initial load, then the play/pause behaviour will work as expected.

P.S. If you find the models on `mount`, you don't need to query your database more than once to find the `Task` model each time. If you read [the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#important-notes), you see that the Laravel Model is a supported type.

Comment: Thanks! this works. I just updated public $taskTime in my runTask()